# Security issue for the MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: mysql, database

I have a chat mobile app talking to a remote MySQL database. The database has 1 table which is:

```
userid | id | message
```

where `userid` is the id of the user, id is the `id` of the message and `message` is of course the message itself.

`id` is primary key

The mobile app generates new messages to be store or it can update existing ones. That's the query I'm currently using in the remote API:

```
INSERT INTO table (userid, id, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE message = ?;
```

If the id doesn't exists then a new row is inserted otherwise it gets updated. It works perfectly but only on a "everyone is honest" client scenario: I'm concerned that users may be able to update messages from other users. If you look closely you'll notice that all it takes to overwrite a message from another user is to send to the API a  packet where `userid` is my real user id, `id` is an id of any pre-existing message already store in the database and `message` is the new text to store.

MySQL will find out that the id already exists, the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` condition will trigger and the message will get updated.. a message of another user!!! MySQL doesn't check that the row being updated belong to the userid (i.e. the userid of the row being updated matched the userid being sent).

Unfortunately the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` doesn't allow for a WHERE clause and I'm stuck at this point

Please note that the userid is not sent by the client but it's set by the server based on the PHP  session variable

Comment: What makes this specific to `ON DUPLICATE KEY`? You'd have the same problem if you had your own logic to check whether to insert or update. The problem is simply that you allow the client to provide information that needs to be determined more securely.

Comment: @Barmar the userid is not sent by the client, it's set by the API based on the session. I didn't want to introduce unnecessary complexity into the question

Comment: In that case, what's the problem? If it's not sent by the client, they can't send someone else's userid.

Comment: @Barmar if I could use a normal update I could use the WHERE userid = ? clause to force a client to update only its own records

Comment: Is `id` a `PRIMARY KEY` set `AUTO_INCREMENT`? If so, why are you stomping old messages with new ones? You should add any application code here to clarify how it's being used. A database doesn't enforce security rules, your application code must.

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini How is that any different? The userid that replaces the `?` parameter could be someone else's userid.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. First you say "send to the API a packet where userid is my real user id," then you say "userid is not sent by the client".

Comment: @Barmar a client doesnt send the userid but it can still update a message from someone else if it provides a message id which belongs to someone else. Please have a look at the query

Comment: Why are you using `INSERT` in the first place? If the client knows the ID, then it must be an existing message, since a new message wouldn't have an ID assigned yet.

Comment: @Barmar because the app is offline first and the MySQL database is used for online syncronization. Records are created by the app so the app itself creates the record id (cryptographic secure id to avoid collisions from other clients). When the app goes online, it uploads its delta on the database. The database will insert or update the record based on the record id. So new records have already an id which is generated at the client side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User id should not from client. use session variable

I assume,

> message id - primary key (auto increment or custom logic to generate id)
>
> user id
>
> message

For new message (easily can say if **message id** is **empty or 0** )

- Use insert query

Edit message (if **message id** is **not empty** ))

- Check the message id exists using `select` query
- Cross verify the **session user id** and **stored user id** are same
- use the `update` query

// Not the best way to use especially in your case

```
INSERT INTO table (userid, id, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `message` = VALUES(`message`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by having the pair `userid,id` as the primary key. This way, the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` will trigger if and only if the client provides a record id which belongs to itself